# Xamarin.ios redirect to specific view controller depending on a received push notification title

Tags: ios, xamarin, notifications

I have an app and I already managed to redirect any notification to a certain view controller.

What I need now, I would like to know if it is possible to get to a certain view controller depending on the push notification title or any attribute that I can set. Let's say that I received two push notifications (or local notifications) with a title "View 1" and "View 2", what I need to do is if I click on the notification "View 1" it redirects me to view1, and when I click on the notification "View 2" it gets me to view2.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set key-value in your notification hub, get the value when clicking the notification and decide which page should be present.

```
public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
{
    string vaule = userInfo["yourKey"] as NSString;

    if(vaule is "View1")
    {
        this.Window.RootViewController = new ViewController1();
    }
    else if (vaule is "View2")
    {
        this.Window.RootViewController = new ViewController2();
    }
}
```